# Where to AWS Boto3 EC2 instance all state codes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there any way to get state code of an instance using boto3's `describe_instances()` method? The official documentation shows following state strings but does not specify codes.

```json
"State": {
    "Code": 123,
    "Name": ["'pending'|'running'|'shutting-down'|'terminated'|'stopping'|'stopped'"]
}
```

Is there any way to get integer codes for each of these states? *(Other than fetching status in each of the states of course!)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **instance-state-code** - The code for the instance state, as a 16-bit unsigned integer. The high byte is used for internal purposes and should be ignored. The low byte is set based on the state represented. The valid values are 0 (pending), 16 (running), 32 (shutting-down), 48 (terminated), 64 (stopping), and 80 (stopped).

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html